# html form to pass variable to php to bash?

Tags: php, html, bash

ok, this is probably more steps than needed.
I have an HTML page that asks for 2 dates (start and end) I want it to accept those dates and send them to a PHP file which will then kick off a script using those dates as variables.

main page:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Calendar lookup </title>
</head>
<link href="stylesheets/common.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<body>

<h1>Calendar Date Range</h1>

<form method="post" action="run_script.php">


Start Date YYYY-MM-DD: <br />
<input type="text" name="Start_Date" size="35" />
<br />

End Date YYYY-MM-DD: <br />
<input type="text" name="End_Date" size="35" />
<br /> <br />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<br />
</form>

</body>
```

that page should pass the dates to  my php file-run_script.php:

```
<?php


$Start_Date = $_POST['Start_Date'];
$End_Date = $_POST['End_Date'];

 exec (sudo sh  "gather.sh $Start_Date $End_Date ");
?>
```

however, it's not kicking off the gather script at all it seems. when I hit the submit button I take me to a blank page /run_script.php and never runs gather.sh (i check where it should be dumping the data nothing shows up)

I know the script works fine if I run sh gather.sh   it does what I want just need to get that PHP file to kick it off for the users.

any thoughts? or is this just the completely wrong way to go about it?

### Edit

As Ed pointed out it has a giant vulnerability in the PHP. so it is the wrong way.

suggestions on another way are appreciated.

Comment: Should be `sudo sh  gather.sh "$Start_Date $End_Date"`

Comment: Please do not deploy this code anywhere; it has a giant injection vulnerability. Anyone able to access the PHP file in a browser could use it to run arbitrary code on your machine.

Comment: Not to mention there is a php syntax error. PHP has no clue what `sudo sh` are. You should be passing that into the string `"sudo sh  gather.sh $Start_Date $End_Date "`

Comment: ah ok! @EdCottrell its all internal no external access.

Comment: @stcoyle Nonetheless, the principle is: never write code you know (or should know) is insecure. The code that is for internal use only is the same code that's likely to get reused in a public context in six months or a year and get your server thoroughly hacked. And that's assuming you don't accidentally make it public before then. Assume it's accessible to your worst enemy.

Comment: @stcoyle why not use PHP and something like mysql or plain-text to store dates, then parse them from the plain text file with PHP

Comment: @DerekPollard yeah im thinking thats probably going to be the end result which is probably going to be a whole other issue haha

Comment: At the very least you should validate that the values that come are really dates and that are in the range you expect them to be.

Comment: Besides the gaping security vulnerability and the incorrect use of `exec` you might want to ensure that the user PHP runs under actually has the correct permissions. Most likely it's `www-data` and that is very restricted in regards to executing arbitrary commands. If you **really** know what you are doing you could add `www-data` to the `sudoers` - if you don't really know what the implications of this are: **don't do it**.